# How to do a razor dropdown with alternate colors for the option list

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

For example how can I make each option element below an alternate color

```
  <select asp-for="AssetCode" class="form-control"
        asp-items="@Model.AssetList">
  </select>
```

Comment: You must use CSS and define it each color depends on some value

Answer (score 0):

Below is demo, you can refer to it.

Colormodel:

```
public class Colormodel
    {
        public  string AssetCode { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AssetList { get; set; }
    }
```

ColorController:

```
public class ColorController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var List = new List<Colormodel>()
            {
                new Colormodel{Id=1, AssetCode="a"},
                new Colormodel{Id=2,AssetCode="b"},
                 new Colormodel{Id =3,AssetCode="c"}
        };

            var Items = List.Select(q => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = q.AssetCode,
                Value = q.Id.ToString()
            });
            var model = new Colormodel
            {
                AssetList = Items,
              
            };

            return View(model);

        }
    }
```

1.If you want to set the color to the text , you can try  .css `color`

Index view:

```
@model Colormodel
 <select  asp-for="AssetCode" class="form-control"
        asp-items="@Model.AssetList">
  </select>
 
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function(){    
    $("#AssetCode option[value='1']").css('color','red');
    $("#AssetCode option[value='2']").css('color', 'green');
    $("#AssetCode option[value='3']").css('color', 'blue');   
     });
  </script>
```

result:

[image]

2.If you want to set the color to the option background , you can try  .css `background`

```
$("#AssetCode option[value='1']").css('background','red');
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Mark C  any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.